# How can I download the Azure .publishsettings file from the command line (by not using a browser)?

Tags: linux, azure

I'm ssh'd into my Ubuntu VM on Azure, and I'm trying to setup the Azure CLI.

Since I plan to use my VM as a Jenkins Slave to run Azure commands thru Azure CLI, I have no need to install a desktop and setup RDP.

What I'd like to do is download the publishsettings file from Azure directly from my SSH session, and then configure Azure CLI thru it.

Is this possible?

The closest thing I could find is this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/issues/975), wherein MS states they plan to fix it and then close the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publish settings file is a convenience so that people don't have to create a self-signed X.509 certificate and then upload it as a [management certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg551722.aspx). The azure account CLI command is documented as accepting a certificate as well as a publish settings file. In theory you should be able to pre-configure an X.509 certificate as a management certificate and use that with the azure CLI without on VM recourse to a browser. I say in theory because I vaguely remember a bug which meant it didn't work.

Of course, you could generate the publish settings file out of band, copy it to the VM, and then use it with the azure CLI.

Comment: I ended up copying a publish settings file from a temporary public container using curl.